# Slony only replicates when intially starting

Tags: postgresql, slony

So I followed the Slony tutorial and was able to replicate my databases, but I've noticed it only works when first starting up. If I leave the replication running any new data never makes it to the slave. The only way I have found to remedy this is to uninstall the cluster/nodes and reinstate them then again replication only happens when starting up.

I followed this tutorial [here](http://slony.info/documentation/2.1/tutorial.html#FIRSTDB)

My steps currently are:

1. Start postgres on both Master and Slave
2. Uninstall cluster/nodes With this script(I have another one for the slave node with the host as that node.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   slonik <<_EOF_
   cluster name = $CLUSTERNAME;

   node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=$TEST_DB host=$MASTERHOST user=test';

   uninstall node ( id = 1 );
   _EOF_
   ```
3. Setup cluster

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   slonik <<_EOF_
   cluster name = $CLUSTERNAME;
   node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=$TEST_DB host=$MASTERHOST user=test';
   node 2 admin conninfo = 'dbname=$TEST_DB host=$SLAVEHOST user=test';
   init cluster (id=1, comment = 'Master Node');

   create set (id=1, origin=1, comment='All test tables');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=1, fully qualified name = 'test.amqp_status', comment='amqp status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=2, fully qualified name = 'test.corba_status', comment='corba status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=3, fully qualified name = 'test.icmp_status', comment='ping status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=4, fully qualified name = 'test.test_status', comment='teststatus');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=5, fully qualified name = 'test.ntp_status', comment='ntp status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=6, fully qualified name = 'test.snmp_status', comment='snmp status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=7, fully qualified name = 'test.subsystem_service_status', comment='subsystem_service status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=8, fully qualified name = 'test.subsystem_status', comment='subsystem status');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=9, fully qualified name = 'test.switch_device_file', comment='switch_device_file');
   set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=10, fully qualified name = 'test.host_status', comment='host status');

   store node (id=2, comment = 'Slave Node', event node=1);
   store path (server = 1, client = 2, conninfo='dbname=$TEST_DB host=$MASTERHOST user=test');
   store path (server = 2, client = 1, conninfo='dbname=$TEST_DB host=$SLAVEHOST user=test');
   _EOF_
   ```
4. Run slon on each node with this command:

   ```
   slon $CLUSTERNAME "dbname=$TEST_DB user=test host=$MASTERHOST"
   ```
5. Run replication script on Master (I've tried forward on no and yes with no difference.)

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   slonik <<_EOF_
   cluster name = $CLUSTERNAME;

   node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=$TEST_DB host=$MASTERHOST user=test';
   node 2 admin conninfo = 'dbname=$TEST_DB host=$SLAVEHOST user=test';

   subscribe set (id = 1, provider = 1, receiver = 2, forward = yes);
   _EOF_
   ```

Once this last script is run within a second my tables have copied over to the slave and I can see the SYNC happening in the slon output of each host, but even thought I see this SYNC message I do not see the tables being updated anymore.

I have manually logged in to PostgreSQL and inserted into the tables. I have also tried using the PSQL command instead and java inserting into postgres. Nothing seems to be seen by Slony past the initial copy.

as for postgres settings I have replication set to 'replica', but have not changed much else as the Slony documentation didn't suggest anything.

I figure I am missing something basic, but please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple minor details...

- I would suggest leaving the "replication" mode alone; Slony manages that itself, and mucking around with it is liable to cause things to break more confusingly.
- FYI, having forwarding on or off is pretty irrelevant if you only have 2 nodes; that won't be important.

My first thought was that perhaps you were only running a slon process against the subscriber node, and not against the origin; that would cause the perceived phenomenon. The slon running against the origin doesn't do any replication work, but it does mark SYNC events, so that subscribers know that they have data to pull. No slon against the master means subscribers think they have no work to do.

A next thought is to see if changes are being successfully captured on the origin. Update some data on the master, and, on the master, look in tables [SlonySchemaName].sl_log_1 and .sl_log_2. The data changes should be captured there; if they're not, then we'd be able start looking to why not.

A further thought... Turn the debugging level up a bit. Info level (log_level = 0) should be enough normally, but when something confusing is happening, head to log_level = 1 which is DEBUG1.

On the origin, all you'll see, for the most part, is that, when busy, SYNCs get generated fairly frequently, and, if not busy, SYNCs get generated infrequently.

The action takes place on the subscriber, and, in the logs, at DEBUG1, you'll get a fair bit more indication of what replication work is going on.

The documentation about Log Analysis should be fairly helpful; see http://www.slony.info/documentation/2.2/loganalysis.html

Comment: So I did try these things sorry I didn't answer in the main question. There is nothing in the sl_log_X. I did try adding debugging, but I think I did -d debug4(no caps) so I will re-try that. Do I need to run the scripts I wrote above on any specific node? I feel like each of those scripts connects to both so running only on the master seemed fine. I ran all the above scripts on only the master.

Comment: Welp it look like having the postgres set to "replica" did it. Thats annoying haha. I read someone to put it like that, but it seems like that wasnt on the Slony site because I can't find it anymore. Also your documentation is sort of weird for log_level, I thought I had to put "Debug4" not 4. That was easy enough to figure out once I saw the first line of output was that it expected an integer.

Comment: There's a clever system behaviour attached to that...  Slony puts a "DenyAccess" trigger onto replicated tables, which causes attempts to Insert/Update/Delete against those tables to fail, so a mis-pointed tool won't shoot the replica in the foot, instead, the updates fail, you get an error message that yells at you "dummy, don't run updates against a replica!", and all's well.
The "magic" then is that the slon process needs to get around that, so, uses 'replica' mode to suppress those triggers.

Comment: The C code has FATAL, ERROR, CONFIG, INFO, DEBUG1 thru DEBUG4; that's how I think about the debugging levels :-)
INFO == level 0.